# Deploy EAR file to WAS 8.5 from command line [Windows]

Tags: deployment, websphere, wsadmin

I need to deploy an EAR file that is located in my windows local drive. I know, we can achieve this by wsadmin.

But not clear on the whole process. Do i need to specify the nodename along with this command

This what i tried so far:-

```
wsadmin install "c://apps/test.ear"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
wsadmin -c "$AdminApp install c:/path/to/app {-usedefaultbindings}"
```

The `-usedefaultbindings` option is just one of many.  See the [Options for the AdminApp object install, installInteractive, edit, editInteractive, update, and updateInteractive commands using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html) topic in the knowledge center for more options.